# Not able to pass string from one fragment to another using Bundle

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a Fragment that contains an expandable ListView the code for which is :

```
package x;

import x.expandablelistadapter.ExpListAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;

//import android.provider.DocumentsContract.Document;

public class EventFragment extends Fragment {
    private String[] categories;
    private String[][] categoryItems;
    private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    private ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    private int lastExpandedGroup;

    public EventFragment() {
        this.lastExpandedGroup = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // get the event categories
        categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eventCategory);
        // get the computer science games
        String[] category1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.csEvents);
        // get the ec games
        String[] category2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ecEvents);
        // get the online games
        String[] category3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.onEvents);
        // get the robotics games
        String[] category4 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rbEvents);
        // get all the category items
        categoryItems = new String[][] { category3, category1, category2,
                category4 };
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_layout, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // get the expandable list view
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.eventListExp);
        expandableListAdapter = new ExpListAdapter(categories, categoryItems,
                getActivity());
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        expandableListView.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandableListView
                .setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                        if (groupPosition != lastExpandedGroup
                                && lastExpandedGroup != -1) {
                            expandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroup);
                        }
                        lastExpandedGroup = groupPosition;
                    }

                });

        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String event = (String) expandableListAdapter.getChild(
                        groupPosition, childPosition);
                EventFragment fragment = new EventFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Event", event);
                Log.d("Bundle", bundle.toString());
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                EventDetailsFragment eventDetailsFragment = new EventDetailsFragment();

                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                fragTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,
                        eventDetailsFragment);
                // fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragTransaction.commit();

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Now on child click event I want to pass the value of child to another fragment.

My second fragment is:

```
package x;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EventDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    String eventString;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        //Log.d("Bundleargs",""+ args.toString());
         if (args  != null && args.containsKey("Event"))
             eventString = args.getString("Event");
         else
             eventString="Nothing";
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eventdetails_layout, container,
                false);


         TextView eventTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.eventTextView);
         eventTextView.setText(eventString);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here I am not able to receive the value stored in the bundle even though the value in the bundle in the first fragment is getting stored properly.

So what may be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

to

```
            eventDetailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

because you are setting bundle for `fragment` but passing  `eventDetailsFragment` instance in `fragTransaction.replace`